# Do we need to disable the trim on an 3rd party SSD before updating a Mac?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, high-sierra, trim

I have a MacBook Pro 13-inch Mid 2012 and I installed an SSD in it. I'd like to upgrade my computer, but I'm not sure if I need to disable the trim before the update and reenable it after. I've heard that it could cause problems, but don't know why.

I have macOS Sierra 10.12.6 and I've enabled the trim since I switched to this operating system.

Comment: I upgraded with TRIM enable (from terminal) and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TRIM is a subset of the ATA commands specific to SSDs.

Can you operate without it?  Sure, but it will treat your SSD as if it were a spinning HDD - impacting performance and lifespan.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trim_(computing)):

> The TRIM command enables an operating system to notify the SSD of
>   pages which no longer contain valid data. For a file deletion
>   operation, the operating system will mark the files sectors as free
>   for new data, then send a TRIM command to the SSD. After trimming, the
>   SSD will not preserve any contents of the block when writing new data
>   to a page of flash memory, resulting in less write amplification
>   (fewer writes), higher write throughput (no need for a
>   read-erase-modify sequence), thus increasing drive life.

If your MacBook Pro came with an SSD, it's enabled by default.  If not, you must enable TRIM when you upgrade to an SSD.